# Received 400 When attempting to send timestamp as request parameter to my rest API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, postman

I am trying to send timestamp request parameter via postman to my API which looks like :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Response<Object>> getTaskStatusList(@RequestParam final Timestamp startDate, @RequestParam final Timestamp endDate){
 //Body

}
```

My request looks like :

```
{{url}}/get-data?startDate=2018-06-27T19:32:21.158+0530&endDate=2018-06-27T19:32:21.158+0530
```

And I got following:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value '2018-06-27T19:32:21.158 0530' of type 'String' for parameter 'startDate'. Type 'Timestamp' was expected."
}
```

Comment: does it work if you declare your controller method parameters as - `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime startDate` ?

Comment: @SabirKhan I want request params of type Timestamp only..don't want to change the type.

Comment: if your method parameter is `java.sql.Timestamp`, then value that you are sending is not a valid `java.sql.Timestamp` value so either send values in [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) (by using `JsonFormat` annotation )or change param type to accept ISO date. You can also write custom deserializer .

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is in a wrong format.

According to [this site](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and ISO-8601, your timestamp should be like:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

Where

```
YYYY = four-digit year
MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

It will probably work then.

Comment: Have tried it. Still, it treats it as string parameter only instead of timestamp.

Comment: Can't you receive it as a String then parse yourself to Date ou Timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Check your timestamp value for all your data items, make sure is in legal format and not empty value.